# How to get Steam user inventory online

Tags: javascript, php, json, steam, steam-web-api

ok so i found out how to get the json after searching for an answer i could not find for like 5 hours.

http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{steamid}/inventory/json/730/2/?trading=1
this brings up the json.

im wondering how can i get the picture of the weapon, name and price and store be able to show it on a webpage...this is for csgo

here if my question isnt clear enough

[Picture of online inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vUOc.png)

thats from csgopowerball.com if you were wondering.

here is what im talking about, thats my inventory, and it grabbed my gun, with name and price and wear. im wondering how im able to grab info from the json to that. cause i dont know what the price or wear is on there.

if you are still confused please add me on skype: pannduuh

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `rgDescriptions` object in your JSON response. It contains an icon_url, which you can use to get the picture from http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/ICON_URL

Comment: i got it thanks, took a while for me to figure out